# follow tutorials pretty easy and fast, but when making own things it looks so bad

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is maybe not a very mechanical question.
So I am student and learning illustrator for the past months, sometimes more
than other weeks. I know most of the tools and such and can pretty replicate
most things when I see it on the web if it is not too advanced.
I follow tutorials and make them pretty decent, it looks the same.

But when I try to create my own things, it looks so bad. I use everything wrong, I forget how to make shapes. I don't know where to put the shadows and so on.

Anyone got advice how I can improve ?

Comment: What kind of "things" are you trying to create specifically? Logos? Illustrations?

Answer (score 1):

Focus on learning to draw.

The problem with tutorials, and even some structured classes, is they focus on the software and learning to use those tools. But tools in themselves don't teach you how to draw.

Knowing what shapes to use to convey something, knowing where to put shadows, and lighting, understanding foreshortening and perspective, are all drawing techniques, not software techniques.

So, if you are strictly using online tutorials, start watching tutorials covering drawing - i.e. shadows, lighting, perspective, anatomy, drapery, foreshortening, dimensioning, etc.

Burne Hogarth, has a series of excellent drawing related books that cover a great many of these topics. All available at Amazon.